# EJB reference configuration

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am currently working on my first Java EE application and I’m facing some injection problems.

For my project I am using JPA, EJB’s and Servlets.
So far I created my entities, the generic DAO, DAO implementation, the services, then the servlet and a jsp page.

I want to inject the JPA entity manager in my DAO classes.
The DAO classes are injected into Services, and the Services are injected into Servlets.

1. The generic DAO interface

   ```
   @Local
   public interface DAO<T> {
       void insert(T item);
       void delete(T item);
   // and so on … }
   ```
2. The generic DAO implementation

   ```
   public class GenericDAO<T> implements DAO<T> {
       @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPU")
       private EntityManager entityManager;
       private final Class<T> entityClass;
       public GenericDAO(Class<T> entityClass) {
           this.entityClass = entityClass;
       }
       @Override
       public void insert(T item) {
           entityManager.persist(item);
       }
   // and so on… }
   ```
3. Generic dao extension for my entity

   ```
   @Stateless
   @LocalBean
   public class PositionDAO extends GenericDAO<Position> {
       public PositionDAO() {
           super(Position.class);
       }
   }
   ```
4. My service interface for Position entity

   ```
   @Local
   public interface PositionService {
       void addPosition(Position position);
       void updatePosition(Position position);
       // and so on … }
   ```
5. My Service impl

   ```
   @Stateless
   @LocalBean
   public class PositionServiceImpl implements PositionService {
       @EJB
       private DAO<Position> positionDao;
       @Override
       public void addPosition(Position position) {
           positionDao.insert(position);
       }  // and so on…

   @WebServlet(name = "RegisterServlet", urlPatterns = {"/register"})
   public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
       @EJB
       PositionService positionService;
   ```

```
Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=online.recruitment.system.service.PositionServiceImpl/positionDao,Local 3.x interface =online.recruitment.system.dao.DAO,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session
```

I put this config in my web.xml but it doesn't work

```xml
<ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>positionDao</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type> 
    <local>online.recruitment.system.dao.DAO</local>
 </ejb-local-ref>
```

Comment: AFAIK, what you're trying to do is not possible with EJBs. You should define a PositionDao interface extending DAO<Position>, and rename your PositionDao to PositionDaoImpl. Then, inject PositionDao rather than DAO<Position>. In fact, I would ditch the interfaces and inject the concrete classes dirctly. They don't bring much to the table.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no needs for the web.xml configuration as you are making the injection using `@EJB` annotation.

Second, you can't inject a generic class using EJB because of  type erasure, you cannot be certain that the injected EJB (`DAO<Position>`) is of the expected type, which will produce a `ClassCastException` in runtime.

Better is tu use JB Nizet's suggestion per comments:

> You should define a PositionDao interface extending DAO, and
>   rename your PositionDao to PositionDaoImpl. Then, inject PositionDao
>   rather  than DAO. In fact, I would ditch the interfaces and
>   inject the concrete classes dirctly. They don't bring much to the
>   table